# Logarithmic function transformations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, transformation

The standard log function form is $a \log[k(x-d)] + c$

Where

$a$ vertically stretches or compresses

$k$ horizontally stretches or compresses

$d$ translates left or right

$c$ translates up or down

If we have $2 \log(2x)$ does this have a vertical translation when rewriting to $\log 4 + \log x$?? And why? Standard form dictates this has no vertical or horizontal shifts?

Comment: 2log2x means a=2 and k=2.  You vertically and horizontally stretch by 2.  log4 + logx means c= log4 .  So does stretching it vertically and horizontally yield the same result as shifting?  Apparently it can.  Think about it.  The curve is uniform shape.  So there is no difference between a curve left alone and a curve that has been blown up.  Except the blown up one has bigger values.  But you always get better values by shifting to the right.  The two are really the same.

Comment: Yes it makes sense that c=log4 but then what is the point of standard form since if x is multiplied by anything (horizontally compressed/stretched) theres an automatic translation up?? We might as well expand all log functions to see the true nature of transformation

Comment: 6 of one half a dozen of the other.  I don't understand your objection.

Comment: At the end, you meant to put $\log4+\log x^2$

Comment: No, the exponent goes directly as the leading coefficient

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with logarithms, vertical shifts, and horizontal stretches/compressions are considered to be one and the same.

$$\log(a\cdot x)=\log(x)+c$$

We don't say it *doesn't* have a vertical shift, it does, but it also has a horizontal stretch/compression that is exactly related to the vertical shifting.

To understand why this is so, return to the definition of the logarithm:

$$\log_{10}(x)=y$$

$$x=10^y$$

Now, try performing a horizontal stretch/compression by a multiple of $10$.

$$10x=10^y$$

$$x=\frac{10^y}{10^1}=10^{y-1}$$

Convert this back to logarithmic form:

$$y-1=\log_{10}(x)$$

$$y=\log_{10}(x)+1$$

In the beginning, we had $10x=10^y$, which in logarithmic form is $y=\log_{10}(10x)$:

$$y=\log_{10}(x)+1=\log_{10}(10x)$$

So that's the basic reason.

Vertical stretches/compressions are not synonymous:

$$a\log(x)=\log(x^a)$$

That is neither a shift nor a stretch, as you can obviously tell.